# How to store formulas, instead of values, in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to work with pandas DataFrame as with an Excel spreadsheet: say, by entering a formula in a column so that when variables in other columns change, the values in this column change automatically? Something like:

```
a  b  c
2  3  =a+b
```

And so when I update 2 or 3, the column `c` also updates automatically.

PS: It's clearly possible to write a function to return `a+b`, but is there any built-in functionality in pandas or in other Python libraries to work with matrices this way?

Comment: For more information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will work in 0.13 (still in development)

```
In [19]: df = DataFrame(randn(10,2),columns=list('ab'))

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
          a         b
0  0.958465  0.679193
1 -0.769077  0.497436
2  0.598059  0.457555
3  0.290926 -1.617927
4 -0.248910 -0.947835
5 -1.352096 -0.568631
6  0.009125  0.711511
7 -0.993082 -1.440405
8 -0.593704  0.352468
9  0.523332 -1.544849
```

This will be possible as `'a + b'` (soon)

```
In [21]: formulas = { 'c' : 'df.a + df.b' }

In [22]: def update(df,formulas):
               for k, v in formulas.items():
                  df[k] = pd.eval(v)


In [23]: update(df,formulas)

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
          a         b         c
0  0.958465  0.679193  1.637658
1 -0.769077  0.497436 -0.271642
2  0.598059  0.457555  1.055614
3  0.290926 -1.617927 -1.327001
4 -0.248910 -0.947835 -1.196745
5 -1.352096 -0.568631 -1.920726
6  0.009125  0.711511  0.720636
7 -0.993082 -1.440405 -2.433487
8 -0.593704  0.352468 -0.241236
9  0.523332 -1.544849 -1.021517
```

You *could* implement a hook into **setitem** on the data frame to have this type of function called automatically. But pretty tricky. You didn't specify *how* the frame is updated in the first place. Would probably be easiest to simply call the update function after you change the values

Answer (score 12):

I don't know it it is what you want, but I accidentally discovered that you can store xlwt.Formula objects in the DataFrame cells, and then, using DataFrame.to_excel method, export the DataFrame to excel and have your formulas in it:

```
import pandas
import xlwt

formulae=[]
formulae.append(xlwt.Formula('SUM(F1:F5)'))
formulae.append(xlwt.Formula('SUM(G1:G5)'))
formulae.append(xlwt.Formula('SUM(H1:I5)'))
formulae.append(xlwt.Formula('SUM(I1:I5)'))

df=pandas.DataFrame(formula)
df.to_excel('FormulaTest.xls')
```

Try it...

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP wanted to export something to Excel. The post is about imitating the Excel behavior using pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Though @jtornero answered a different question, he answered mine, for which I'm grateful!

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no way to do this exactly in the way that you describe.

In pandas 0.13 there will be a new `DataFrame.eval` method that will allow you to evaluate an expression in the "context" of a `DataFrame`. For example, you'll be able to `df['c'] = df.eval('a + b')`.

Comment: does the string in eval support functions , like, df['c'] = df.eval('a.diff() + b') ?

Comment: No. Store the result of a function call in a variable.

Comment: Is it possible to add function support in string in next version?Even though not bring any performance upgrade. For that will let dataframe accept the user input expression and caculate the result accordingly. (my current solution is using pyparsing to parse and modify the expression, then exec it, somewhat ugly)

Comment: Maybe. I'm concerned about possible security issues with allowing arbitrary function calls.

Comment: Even python offer eval and exec, so the security is depend on how to use it . dataframe.eval only support arithmatic is too limited.

Comment: It's not only arithmetic, it supports a fairly comprehensive subset of Python expressions. Read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html#supported-syntax).